# Self resizing ListView in QML

Tags: qt, qml

How can I create a ListView in QML that resizes itself to the amount of items, but max n? I tried this:

```
onCountChanged: height = Math.min(n, count) * contentItem.children[0].height
```

But it results in `TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined`. I assume that using this approach the ListView being of height 0 does not instanciate the children, because if I set it to height=1 on count 0 it works.

Comment: Try `height: `[`contentHeight`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtquick-flickable.html#contentHeight-prop).

Comment: Ah, I missed the 'n' here. I assume this is because the items are not instantiated yet, so you can use nullish and optional chaining operators like `height: Math.min(contentHeight, n * (itemAtIndex(0)?.height ?? 0) + (n - 1) * spacing)` to prevent this error. Also, I recommend using a declarative approach.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it assumes all your delegates are the same height. For instance, had you had `delegate: Rectangle { width: 100; height: 100 + index * 10 }` you'll realize that this is not a general solution. If you give us some specific examples of your delegate, then, we can provide some optimal means of measuring it (including TextMetrics or invisible delegates) that may be suitable. But, if you're looking for a generalize solution, you cannot avoid measuring the content.

Comment: I think it's better to change the title to "Adjust the size of the ListView to fit [n] items." Also, I might have the right answer by using `PathView`. If the other solutions didn't satisfy your needs, I can provide it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]

Solution 1: TextMetrics

Using `TextMetrics` you can get the size of a representative delegate. From that, you can size your ListView accordingly, e.g.

```
ListView {
    property TextMetrics tm: TextMetrics { text: "HELLO" }
    implicitWidth: tm.width
    implicitHeight: tm.height * 5
    model: ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight", "Nine","Ten"]
    delegate: Label { text: modelData }
}
```

You can [Try the ListView TextMetrics Demo Online](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACA3icZVGxTsMwEN3zFSePgCKExJINaFGHQKlSwYAYTHpKTjhx5VybRlX+nbNbpYl6i+/Z7/m9s6naWsew4tWO8r+IJjB+sTU7a5roQxcIxwikmNhgAiqlhj8JW1jjgd+QHeUNzLCyKtCG45PK19bZLTruJgqukgk+AguS+xfzNF0q6Ae5ZDOUE3/RhstEhHHrO7iFh/sr0gKpKDmwytDCDTwOrCyXqcyzdvFeAlGuTXLZGyX21Z7sRh5hFis23UgVP5lWd82yHmiX5JXdoDh8q2WN6g7UurVhKR0G/Gp3Lqy0FzzxOZfK6OAZGe6x9s3cz+SbdzrfKfvwM2jFEAvN8lGp/kUzPGuIMtOsz/H6qP8HE4WUDQ==)

Solution 2: Hidden internal ListView

If each delegate varies in width or size, then, we can determine the height by sampling n records with an hidden internal ListView.

```
ListView {
    id: listView
    property ListView internal: ListView {
        model: listView.model.filter((e,i,n) => i < 5)
        delegate: Label { text: modelData }
    }
    implicitWidth: contentItem.childrenRect.width + 20
    implicitHeight: internal.contentHeight
    clip: true
    model: ["One","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven", "Eight", "Nine","Ten"]
    delegate: Label { text: modelData }
}
```

You can [Try the Hidden Internal ListView Demo Online](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=AAACrnicjVFNTwIxEL3vr5jsCSJpjImXjZr4GUiIiBg9GA+1O7ITS7spAwsh/HfbpSygHJxLZ17nvem80qS0jmHIwxmp74QOSnFrDTurp8mTHCOsEvDBxBozSLuU52igZxidkRr6NOVXwiqtu7ZVJIWgPAMd4QYsnS3R8XJHoCiYHdMIMbE56p2UqGvxRdrzWi3sUMe04fIKCC7gvH1A9Y04luyf35efqGEFjAvONpJ3kiWsm/5d5k3RpIjfKOciA+VNQcM9xolQBencoXlGxaIK93ACZ6d/qF2kceEHbZcTUWSDN+0j5d3WN9KJuTeFVHChwX7ZUG1eszes9tP6ecs9lrjWlVxOB+bIYkpTmQG7GTZQNPc9HRhMO5C+VLY+Cod1/WBnrj5p7uuD0THSES1CxwjnaEJyH1YMySNFTY/DR8P976esk/UPfXHGfw==)

Comment: The problem is that I need to get the size of N items. This approach just shows them all. However, thank you.

Comment: Create a hidden list view who's model contains the subitems you require. If your input model was a JavaScript you hidden list view can use an inline filter lambda function.